# Wifi Doesn't connect to internet in my i5801

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-apollo

in my phone i can connect to any wifi but when i start browser or market or any application that requires internet. It shows no network connection.

I have tried following things

**Tried several different wifi network,

forget network and connect again and enter password,

restart device**

Following is my Device information
**Device : Samsung Galaxy i5801,

OS : android 2.2, 
Baseband version : I5801DDJP2,

Build Number : FROYO.DDJP6,

Kernel Version : 2.6.32.9**

any help is appriciated

Comment: Are you rooted? Check in WiFi advanced settings that port/proxy settings are blank or as required by the router.

Comment: hey thanks .... you almost solved it as i go to setting's advance option i noticed i have checked use static IP address and given some fix ip address ... that's why wifi was not working

Answer (score 1):

as i go to setting's advance option i noticed i have checked use static IP address and given some fix ip address ... that's why wifi was not working. removing that everything works

Answer (score 1):

Are you rooted? Check in WiFi advanced settings that port/proxy settings are blank or as required by the router.

UPDATE: Converting comment to answer.